# Google Analytics Event Tracking isn't firing from iframe

Tags: google-analytics

I have a site that I'm working on which is using a email sign up form inside an iFrame (for random CMS reasons, this has been the work around). I am attempting to install the Event tracking in to the iFrame so that we can see the actual conversion.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
i[r] = i[r] || function () {
    (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
}, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
a = s.createElement(o),
m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
a.async = 1;
a.src = g;
m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

ga('create', 'UA-#######-1', 'site.org');
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id='header'><span>Get the latest treatment tips</span> <span style='color:     #c9c9c9; padding: 0 5px;'>|</span> Sign up for e-news</div>
<form name='signup' id='signup' method='post' action='index.php'>
<input type='text' class='input' name='email' id='email' onfocus="if(this.value == 'Your email') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Your email'; }" value='Your email' />
<input type='text' class='input' name='zip' id='zip' onfocus="if(this.value == 'Zip code') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Zip code'; }" value='Zip code' />
<input onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'newsletter', 'sign-up', {'nonInteraction': 1});" type='submit' id='submit' value='Sign up &raquo;' class='submit' name='submit' />
</form>
```

Previously, someone had put the ga('send', 'event'...) code in the script section, under ga('create', 'UA-'...) and it fired every time the page loaded. So, I've seen it actually work. It just doesn't seem to be firing on the button click itself.

I have also tried firing it onSubmit and that also is not working.

So, I'm not really sure why it isn't going at this stage.

Help! Thank you!

Comment: Share the full page code. Also open it outside of the iframe. Check that it works then. Try debugging with the Google Analytics Debugger Chrome Extension. Report any errors the extension gives.

Comment: In your HTML, this does not show that the tracking is coming from an Iframe. You really cannot directly track interaction in an **Iframe**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Gbueh) which adds the missing start and end to your HTML works and I can see it sending data to Google Analytics.

I've added `return false;` to your `onclick` just so that it didn't submit anywhere.

As you can see from the codepen, it is called from within the iframe.

Comment: So, what you're saying is that it _is_ working?

I guess I will have to check analytics in a day or so to see if it is coming through. It isn't coming through in RealTime though. I'm also not seeing conversions _or_ events.

Comment: The codepen *does* work. If you substitute your UA-XXXXX-YY code into the JavaScript, it should appear. GA Debugger reports it as being sent. You should look at your real time results to see if it appears. Also, add the full HTML in the question - that helps with any typo errors that may be present.

Comment: It looks like it is working according to GA. I had been on Realtime previously trying to fire it and it just wouldn't fire (which lead me to do all the debugging to start).

I just wanted to reply and thank you for your time! It is working as of this morning, and the bit of confidence you gave me really helped.